# Complete list of default values for JSHint options?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, jshint

Where can I get the complete list of JSHint default options. I tried searching online but couldn't find anything.

EDIT: 
I mean a list of default **values** for *all* options, in  case it wasn't clear :)

Comment: [Seriously!?](http://www.jshint.com/docs/#options)

Comment: @Alexander edited to clarify :)

Comment: This is a useful question. Mods: please vote to reopen.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can look on `boolOptions`, `valOptions` and `invertedOptions` objects directly in jshint sources:

https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc

If you are confused with comments, you can refer to options section in jshint help:

http://jshint.com/docs/options/

Comment: Ah thanks, just what I was looking for. I think this list should be available as a separate link/document, without requiring someone to see the source code. Not a big deal, but would mean easier/faster access and better search-ability using a search engine.

Comment: There is an example .jshintrc in the 'examples' directory of the project:

https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc

Note:  At present, the example file still includes the 'predef' option which has been deprecated.  I have submitted a pull request to change this to the new option 'globals'.  This lets you specify an object containing the options:

    'globals': { 'myglobal': false }

Comment: This is wrong, the first link does not represents the defaults used for JSHint itself. It seems to be related to the site only. There is no clear documentation for the development tool, that's crazy.

Comment: That example is incomplete. It does not include option `es3`, for instance.

Comment: I think that maybe [this is the file](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/src/options.js) that @netme would have intended to link to ([see revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15643184/revisions)). However, I don't know if the values in that file fully reflect JSHint's actual default behavior either. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37897772/1924128).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that page contains the list of default options, and that file mentioned in [@netme's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15643184/1924128) has no effect on JSHint's behavior. [Quoting](https://github.com/jshint/jshint.github.io/pull/18#issuecomment-87332181) a JSHint project maintainer:

> Actually, that file is just an example--it has no effect on JSHint's
>   behavior. While it might match the current default behavior, there's
>   no guarantee that it will continue to do so.
>
> This is why [the "options" documentation](http://jshint.com/docs/options/) segments the options by the
>   categories "enforcing" and "relaxing". Notice how all the "relaxing"
>   options are about suppressing warnings--these are the constraints that
>   JSHint imposes by default.

While this makes sense once you understand it, it is confusing to a lot of people (myself included), and [may change in the future](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1223#issuecomment-106612513).