# What all jshint default rules are being applied if not configured with .jshintrc file

Tags: javascript, jshint, gulp-jshint

I have not configured any external .jshintrc file in my application or defined in package.json. However there are some rules being checked by default in jshint. How can I get the list of those rules? I'm using "jshint": "^2.9.4", "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.4".

Edit: This question is not for getting the list of all rules, but for the default rules applied without any configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complete list of default values for JSHint options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642903/complete-list-of-default-values-for-jshint-options)

Comment: I think that answer gives list of all rules, not the one being applied without mentioning .jshintrc file. I'm asking for the default checking happening without the config file.

Comment: That answer has what you want, the the default values of all rules.  All rules are "applied without mentioning"; that's how JSHint works,  it's just that the default values for some (eg. `camelcase`) are false, and those "aren't applied".  Regardless, I highly encourage you to look into eslint: it's far more powerful, popular, and modern.